# Error using Log4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, log4r

I have a problem using Log4r.

```
uninitialized constant Log4r::Logger::RootLogger
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800326), but still got an error:

```
>> require "log4r"
=> true
>> Log4r::DEBUG
NameError: uninitialized constant Log4r::DEBUG
>> Log4r::Logger.root
=> uninitialized constant Log4r::Logger::RootLogger
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/log4r-1.1.11/lib/log4r/staticlogger.rb:5:in `root'
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you using Log4r and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using Log4r in my App - for logs. But I see this passenger error in browser - when trying to access my App.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Uninitialized constant Log4r::DEBUG (NameError) problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799823/ruby-uninitialized-constant-log4rdebug-nameerror-problem)

Comment: There is a major change with V1.1.11 (published yesterday), so I would recommend to use the previous version 1.1.10 (see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934944/676874)). I created a [bug report for it](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29856&group_id=203&atid=851)

Comment: Yesterday I found out what was the problem , since the error was `from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/log4r-1.1.11`, and this version was released just yesterday, I guessed they have a problem with it. So I forced the previous version, and everything works fine.

Comment: My [bug report](http://rubygems.org/gems/log4r) leads to a roll back of log4r 1.1.11. It is removed from http://rubygems.org/gems/log4r . @user2503775 You could close your question and accept my answer, it contains the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with `Log4r::Logger.root` is version depending (the actual version 1.1.11 has this problem).

You may use the [previous log4r-version 1.1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693862/how-do-i-require-a-specific-version-of-a-ruby-gem):

```
gem 'log4r', '<=1.1.10' #or '= 1.1.10'
require 'log4r'
Log4r::Logger.root
```

---

log4r defines the constants like `Log4r::DEBUG` with the creation of the first logger.

You need a `Log4r::Logger.new('dummy')` before you have access to the level constants.

```
require 'log4r'

p defined? Log4r::INFO   #false
Log4r::Logger.new('dummy')
p defined? Log4r::INFO   #constant -> is defined
```

Some background:
There is a constant `Log4r::Log4rConfig::LogLevels` defining the different levels. The level-constants are defined, when the first logger is created. You may define them also with `Log4r.define_levels(*Log4r::Log4rConfig::LogLevels)`

This technique allows it to [create loggers with different logging levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938416/how-can-i-define-my-own-levels-in-log4r-without-a-conflict-with-other-log4r-logg).

Answer (score 0):

Although`Log4r::Logger.root` no longer enables the constants, the code included later on in the answer you referred to *does* introduce the constants:

```
Log4r.define_levels(*Log4r::Log4rConfig::LogLevels)
```

per the following:

```
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > require 'log4r'
 => true 
2.0.0p247 :002 > Log4r.define_levels(*Log4r::Log4rConfig::LogLevels)
 => 5 
2.0.0p247 :003 > Log4r::DEBUG
 => 1 
2.0.0p247 :004 >
```

Comment: Same undefined constant error for accessing `Log4r::DEBUG`? (See updated answer for Ruby version information I'm testing with).